# Android Not Allow some symbols in Textview

Tags: android

I am retrieving text from web server in that text & symbol is there when i try to display that data & after text is not displaying like (Android & Java) "Android" text is displaying "& Java" text is not displaying so what should i do to display all data in my text view.

Thanks,
Murali.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `URLDecoder` to decode your strings.

```
URLDecoder.decode(myWebString, HTTP.UTF-8) /* <--- last argument is encoding character set   or use */  
URLDecoder.decode(myWebString);
```

Plus, check if you have added something like `android:maxLines=1` in your layout xml.